# Ignoring some citations in reference list, but keeping consecutive numbering

Tags: biblatex

I'm writing a document where I would like to separate citations in two categories: one "project internal" category, which is numbered and printed at the end with a `\printbibliography` as usual, and one "external" category, which should just be in a footnote, and not be included in the global reference numbering. Is that possible to do (using biblatex and biber)?

Something like this example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[paperheight=7cm]{geometry}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{projectpaper1,
    author = {Aauthor, A.},
    year = {2001},
    title = {Title},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    keywords = {internal},
  }
  @book{projectpaper2,
    author = {Zauthor, Z.},
    year = {2001},
    title = {Title},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    keywords = {internal},
  }
  @book{externalpaper1,
    author = {Bauthor, B.},
    year = {2001},
    title = {Title},
    publisher = {Publisher},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Our paper \cite{projectpaper1} extends on the old and boring state
of the art\footnote{\fullcite{externalpaper1}} as also demonstrated in 
\textcite{projectpaper2}. 

\printbibliography[keyword={internal}]

\end{document}
```

should then produce a reference at the end with two *consecutively numbered* references. However, in all my attempts, I have not been able to get something better than the example below.
[image]

Comment: Can you show a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)? This definitely depends on the sorting scheme you use and the bibliography style you use.

Comment: At the moment the best guess I can offer is `defernumbers`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `defernumbers` option. If it is enabled, the numeric labels are assigned only when the bibliography is printed. This normally makes sure that the numbering in the bibliography is consecutive as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[paperheight=7cm]{geometry}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{projectpaper1,
    author = {Aauthor, A.},
    year = {2001},
    title = {Title},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    keywords = {internal},
  }
  @book{projectpaper2,
    author = {Zauthor, Z.},
    year = {2001},
    title = {Title},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    keywords = {internal},
  }
  @book{externalpaper1,
    author = {Bauthor, B.},
    year = {2001},
    title = {Title},
    publisher = {Publisher},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Our paper \cite{projectpaper1} extends on the old and boring state
of the art\footfullcite{externalpaper1} as also demonstrated in 
\textcite{projectpaper2}. 

\printbibliography[keyword={internal}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! In my full case (non MWE) I also had to add the `sorting=none` option to biblatex to get the citations in the correct order. It would be even better if this could be combined with normal `nty` sorting, but this works too.

Comment: @Supernormal This should also work with `sorting=nty` (in fact it does in the MWE). You may have to delete the auxiliary files if you change the sorting scheme or change the state of `defernumbers`. Delete the `.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf` files and try again with `\usepackage[defernumbers=true, sorting=nty]{biblatex}`.

Comment: I see. The problem in my original document is probably that I also have partial bibliographies (with selected keywords) before the final complete bibliography at the end, which, in combination with `defernumbers`, changes the order of the numbers.

Comment: @Supernormal Ah, though luck. If your setup is too crazy, this might not work.